# Part of the HTTPS response is changing on every session

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a HTTP response code. A part of it was changing with application upgrade, so I have created a variable for this and changing the variable after each upgrade and so that it will be automatically updated throughout the JMeter script.

```
Language|aB5U0Easj5xXnirzSu4eYyOxICkTU9uEgH4TPx/A++/hc6XBB3sgFdHmvXLriQxFq9RCj4T1Zq+fvzXouImGRIc93NkzkPUEMR1xqwMipVw4A4jJRruIBoLQ6SnP6JfOM3O7M0fV2bhJEHuRAoI04WmYI5eRfNCZhvG9e6Ye9h/8qyk8YRCMRfSjqaA1aZKAXPv1yYPFYXej+WDAt8L82LY/jW3URLc7LLDz/da87CZi3MLJgwRJvjhwB1fBu1Wp4mIR0e79ipNeGJyYY7ADxir0r9cYP611NTj+WF4tR5P7/epeDgexHXpuI/o2+q+vaALUn4+QikI+8KtSi5zE0g9oMJ39o/MIWpJIRAr0p4WmUoROB+6nTyNPG0MZaxKkuboD/7c/mdWzDOeB4eBOljGQpwg1PB53eWrSQJ8Gf7utR05sMOe87worG8lm34oAVlU/H32JzY82ig==
```

The above is the part which is changing and I have created a Variable as Language. And everything is fine till now.

Now, I am facing a new problem after upgrading my application. This variable is changing with every new login, because of this was unable to run the load test. It is giving me the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while decrypting message, close tab or re-login
```

Can someone came across similar issue or if anybody has some idea how to solve this. Please help me !!

Answer (score 0):

So basically you are doing what is known as a "Correlation". The error you are getting is mostly related to correlation. when you are replaying the script, you are using dynamic value from the recording script which is expired.

Check the following:

1. Have you replaced all the changing values in the scripts with your variable? Maybe you 
   missed some parts. Some values could be in a request url or in a body data of a Post
   request.
2. Check for other values that are changing, sometimes you will have many values to be 
   correlated, not just one (ex. JSessionID, CSRF token and ...)
3. What tool you are using to search for dynamic values and their locations? You can use
   JMeter response to check for dynamic values but it is easier if you use Fiddler or if 
   you know LoadRunner, you can use its scripts comparison capabilities.